# swift - retain cycle when calling inner function?

Tags: swift, retain-cycle

Do I have a retain cycle when inner function `progressComplete` is calling inside closure without weak self and inside of it (`progressComplete`) i use self?

```
class SomeClass{

   var manager = Manager()
   var someVar:Int? 

    func doSomething(completion:((Bool) -> Void)?) {
        
        func progressComplete(_ success:Bool) {
            self.someVar = nil
            completion?(success)
        }
        
        self.manager.requestData { success in
            progressComplete(success)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I have a retain cycle

Yes, in the sense that you probably mean it. `self` (the SomeClass) is retaining the Manager, and the Manager, once `doSomething` has been called, is retaining the callback method `progressComplete` which refers to `self`.

So, it's not a permanent situation (a true leak), but SomeClass cannot go out of existence until such time as the Manager's `requestData` has performed its callback. It is easy to confirm this experimentally, and you can see it in the memory graph:

[image]

That's not necessarily a bad thing! But if it's going to be a problem, then you need to fix it.

However, note that `weak self` won't help you here, as there is *no place to say it*. You can only say `weak self` in the body of an *anonymous* function — and you don't have any anonymous functions!

So the correct way to write this, if you are concerned about it, would be to abandon your separate `progressComplete` function and write the callback as an anonymous function, and do the weak–strong dance, like this:

```
    self.manager.requestData { [weak self] success in
        if let self = self {
            self.someVar = nil
            completion?(success)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Better to have this with using **weak self** closure like this eg.

```
class SomeClass{

   var manager = Manager()
   var someVar:Int? 

    func doSomething(completion:((Bool) -> Void)?) {
        
        func progressComplete(_ success:Bool) {
            self.someVar = nil
            completion?(success)
        }
        
        // Use [weak self]
        self.manager.requestData { [weak self] success in
            self?.progressComplete(success)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe because your code does not compile?